# Toggling image border color on click

Tags: jquery

Referencing this Fiddle ( http://jsfiddle.net/j5uGN ), how can I toggle a clicked image's border color between `#efefef` and `#3f96cf` so that it is `#efefef` when the image appears to be unchecked (aka has a class of "nocheck")? I already have a click event firing on img.check, so how do I go about chaining commands together to change a different element?

Is my question clear?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this:

Javascript click event:

```
$(this).find('img.fb_thumbnail').toggleClass("uncheckedborder");
```

Css:

```
div#friend_box img.fb_thumbnail.uncheckedborder {
    border:3px solid #efefef !important;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/j5uGN/5/

Answer (score 1):

```
$("div.friend").click(function() {
    if( $(this).find('img.nocheck').length > 0) {
        $(this).find('img.nocheck').removeClass("nocheck");
        $(this).find('img.fb_thumbnail').css("border-color", "#3f96cf");            
    } else {
          $(this).find('img.check').addClass("nocheck");
          $(this).find('img.fb_thumbnail').css("border-color", "#efefef");
    }
});​
```

[updated jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/j5uGN/3/)